# How to resolve "Unit JclCompression was compiled with a different version of sevenzip.IOutArchive"?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to use the JclCompression unit, but when I do, the compiler always says:

```
Unit JclCompression was compiled with a different version of sevenzip.IOutArchive
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I tried recompiling/installing my JEDI installation, but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is finding a DCU that was compiled with a previous version of Delphi.  You don't say what version of Delphi you are using, but DCU's from one version won't work with those of different version.

The first thing to check is to see if you have your paths right.  If you have compiled the JCL previously, it may be that your path is causing the compiler to find the old DCU files, and thus the error.

In addition, the problem may be that you have an out of sync version of Sevenzip code as well.

Bottom line:  the compiler is finding a DCU that isn't compatible with your current version of Delphi.  Either:

- get the right DCU version
- find the source and compile it
- Ensure that the compiler is looking in the right place for what you are trying to compile

Comment: You're right!  I had removed a conflicting pas file, but forgot to remove the corresponding dcu file.  Took it out, and it worked!  Thanks for your help!  Nice to be helped a blog writer I follow often. :)