# How to resolve “Unit JclCompression was compiled with a different version of sevenzip.IOutArchive”?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, jedi

There is already a similar question([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954702/how-to-resolve-unit-jclcompression-was-compiled-with-a-different-version-of-seve)).The thing is I don't understand what unit I have to delete.

I have installed the latest JCL library and added 'JclCompression' to the uses list in a unit and I get the error: "Unit JclCompression was compiled with a different version of sevenzip.IOutArchive".

Please explain to me in a simpler way how to resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it means is that you have an outdated version of JCLCompression.DCU sitting around.  The compiler tries to use a DCU first if it can find it, and then recompile from the PAS files if there's no DCU available or if the DCU is stale..  What this error means is that the DCU is stale and it's trying to rebuild from the source, but it can't find sevenzip.pas, which JclCompression uses.  Try finding Sevenzip.pas and add it to your project's search path, or to Delphi's search path.

Comment: I get 62 errors now,please help me.After I add the path to JclCompression.pas in Delphi's search path ,the error disappears ,but the unit cannot compile.I get many,many errors inside it.Please help on his one too. :(

Comment: @John: I don't know what sort of errors you're getting.  Try posting this as another question, with a log of the compiler output, and maybe someone will be able to help with that.